# SQL - Find time duration duration with only eventstarttime (query)

Tags: sql, informix, duration

I am trying to figure out how to query the time duration between events.  The table I am looking at is called **agentstatedetail**.  And within the table for simplicity purposes there are 2 columns, **agentid** and **eventdatetime**.  The table lists agentid's and the event start date and time.  After each event a new event is recorded with a new event date and time.  I am trying to subtract the latest **eventdatetime**  from the prior **eventdatetime** that matches up with the same agent.  I am unable to paste the picture of the table because I am new but I have pasted the code I have worked on.  Thank you and I hope someone can help!!!

There are 2 query examples I tried but they did not work. Note: this is in SQL Informix but I do not care if someone can shed some light even if it is in MySQL.

```
select  asd1.*, asd2.* from agentstatedetail asd1
 join agentstatedetail asd2 
on asd1.agentid=asd2.agentid
 and asd1.eventdatetime < asd2.eventdatetime
and 0=(select count(*) from agentstatedetail asd3
    where asd3.agentid =asd1.agentid
        and asd3.eventdatetime between asd1.eventdatetime and asd2.eventdatetime
)
where asd1.eventdatetime BETWEEN '2015-5-1 13:00:00' AND '2015-5-2    13:00:00'
and asd2.eventdatetime BETWEEN '2015-5-1 13:00:00' AND '2015-5-2 13:00:00'
and asd1.agentid=1953 


select  asd1.*, asd2.* 
from agentstatedetail asd1
join agentstatedetail asd2 
on asd1.agentid=asd2.agentid
and asd1.eventdatetime < asd2.eventdatetime

left join agentstatedetail asd3
on asd3.agentid =asd1.agentid
    and asd3.eventdatetime between asd1.eventdatetime and       asd2.eventdatetime
where asd1.eventdatetime BETWEEN '2015-5-1 13:00:00' AND '2015-5-2 13:00:00'

 and asd1.agentid=1953 
and asd3.agentid is null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select b.agentId, 
   b.eventdatetime start,
   e.eventdatetime end,
   e.eventdatetime - b.eventdatetime ElapsedTime
From agentstatedetail b
    left join agentstatedetail e
         on e.agentid = b.agentid
            and e.eventdatetime =
                (Select Min(eventdatetime)
                 from agentstatedetail 
                 where agented = b.agentid
                     and eventdatetime > b.eventdatetime)
```

Comment: I tried working with that code but I don't think I am doing something correct.  Is this what you mean?select asd1.agentid,
   asd1.eventdatetime as starttime,
   asd2.eventdatetime as endtime,
   asd2.eventdatetime - asd1.eventdatetime as elapsedtime

from agentstatedetail asd1
   left join agentstatedetail asd2
   on asd1.agentid=asd2.agentid
     and asd2.eventdatetime = (select min(eventdatetime)
                               from agentstatedetail
                               where agentid = asd1.agentid
                               and eventdatetime > asd1.eventdatetime)

Comment: yes, I used tables aliases `b` for begin, and `e` for end, output column aliases `start` for startTime, and `End` for endtime, and the SQL keyword `AS` is optional, otherwise, what you have appears to be the same...

Comment: What behavior are you seeing from your query ?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I am getting an unknown SQL type 110 and not sure what that means.  I understand it is a descriptor type but not sure where to look in my code.

Comment: This may be an Informix specific issue, I'm sorry, but I don't know Informix, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: Yes I figured that as well.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: So I figured it out, I had to cast the eventdatetime because Informix is very picky.  It runs very quick now!!!!

Answer (score 0):

select asd1.agentid, asd1.eventtype, asd2.eventdatetime , asd1.eventdatetime,
((asd2.eventdatetime-asd1.eventdatetime)::interval minute(9) to minute::char(10)::int) As IntervalMinutes,
((asd2.eventdatetime-asd1.eventdatetime)::interval second(9) to second::char(10)::int) As Interval

from agentstatedetail asd1
   join agentstatedetail asd2
   on asd1.agentid=asd2.agentid
     and asd2.eventdatetime = (select min(eventdatetime)
                               from agentstatedetail
                               where agentid = asd1.agentid
                               and eventdatetime > asd1.eventdatetime)
where asd1.agentid=1953 and
asd1.eventdatetime BETWEEN '2015-5-1 13:00:00' AND '2015-5-2 13:00:00'

Comment: @ Charles Bretana, so I got the query to run but one problem I am having is when there is an eventdatetime with the same time as the next eventdatetime (0 duration).  Since the subquery I am running is only taking eventdatetime>asd1.eventdatetime is creating some noise in the data with a duplicate entry.  When I say eventdatetime>=asd1.eventdatetime the starttime and endtime are the same.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!